# how to extract value from website with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working on a price web scraping code to extract data such as prices, quantities and so on. I used the code with BeautifulSoup to extract text from html tag  of the targeted website.
However, it returned with a bunch of text and I don't know how to split or separate them before printing those into csv file.

```js
from urllib import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=568-3651-5-ND'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.body.script
filename = "products.txt"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "data"
f.write(headers)
data = containers.text
f.write(data + "\n")
f.close()
```

and it returned with:

```html
var utag_data = {
            page_site: 'US',
            page_language: 'en',
            wt_use_udo: 'True',
            page_content_group: 'Part Search',
            page_content_sub_group: 'Part Detail',
            page_title: 'Part Detail',
            page_type: 'PS',
            page_sub_type: 'PD',
            page_id: 'PD',
            **pn_sku: '1740-1017-ND',**
            part_id: '1154763',
            **part_available: '4324',**
            transaction_type: 'v',
            transaction_quantity: '1',
            supplier_id: '1740'
                , part_search_filter: 'No Filter'
                , **part_search_term: '568-3651-5-ND'**
                , part_search_term_ext: '568-3651-5-ND'
                    , part_search_results_count: 1
            , video_source: 'Part Detail'
        }
```

I tried with find and regex but results were not as I expect with quantity (part_available: '4324') and sku_num (pn_sku: '1740-1017-ND'). I am new to python and coding, please leave any comments.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use regular expression, you'd better to use json. But the given script is not strictly-formatted json. Instead you can use [`yaml` parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML).

```
import yaml
data = yaml.load(containers.text.replace('var utag_data =', '', 1))
with open('products.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('part,sku\n')
    f.write('{},{}\n'.format(data['part_available'], data['pn_sku']))
```

---

Result csv file content:

```
part,sku
4324,1740-1017-ND
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine and printed out exactly data